# How to do Laplace transform in this?

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

How to solve this problem...

[image]

I tried yo split the numerator but I still don't know what to do.

Comment: The denominator is $(s+2)^2+1$. Now write the numerator as $s+8=(s+2)+6$ and use the table of transformations to find that $f(t)=e^{-2t}\cos(t)+6e^{-2t}\sin(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Laplace Transform [formulae](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaplaceTransform.html),

$$L^{-1}\dfrac b{(s-a)^2+b^2}=e^{at}\sin bt$$ and $$L^{-1}\dfrac{s-a}{(s-a)^2+b^2}=e^{at}\cos bt$$

Now $s^2+4s+5=(s+2)^2+1^2$

Can you recognize $a,b$ here?

Write $s+8=(s+2)+6\cdot1$

Comment: I forgot this formula.... Thanks for the answer